# JS How to get id of current section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder how to get the id property of section itself, the following example is what I am trying to realize:
I have a mapping dictionary predefined, and I hope the defaultValue of section to be mapping['id']. The problem is the id might be changing so I need to get the current id of each section.

```
mapping = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c'}

    <div> 
        <select defaultValue=mapping[{id_of_this_select_object}] id='1' />
    </div>
```

The result should be:

```
        <div> 
            <select defaultValue='a' id='1' />
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do that :

```
<div> 
   {Object.keys(mapping).map(k => <select defaultValue={mapping[k]} id={k} />) }
</div>
```

You can check this by running below code snippet :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const mapping = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c'};

  return (
    <div>
      
      <p>As answer to your question :</p>
      {Object.keys(mapping).map(k => <div><select defaultValue={mapping[k]} id={k} key={mapping[k]} /></div>) }
  
      <p>But , I think you are expecting something like this :</p>
      <select>
        { Object.keys(mapping).map(k => <option defaultValue={mapping[k]} id={k} value={k} key={mapping[k]}>{mapping[k]}</option>) }
      </select>    
    </div>


  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, sorry for the unclarity, I have updated the question. I don't want all keys in mapping to be returned. I would need to let the defaultValue updating with the change of id.

Comment: @YuqinXu, and how do you change that id? select is dropdown and you have mentioned section in your question title, will you please explain bit more, what is that you actually need?

Comment: Sure, so I have multiple selections in the website, when I select one dropdown, the value of this selection will change from defaultValue to the selected options. But if I refresh the page, the content of these selections will change back to the defaultValue. So I want to use id as the key, and record each selection in mapping file. So if I refresh the page, previous selection will keep.

Comment: @YuqinXu, in that case you need to store that `id` in `localstorage` and on `componentDidMount` you should check if there is any available id or not, if there is then just `this.setState({ selectedId})` and you are done, `defaultValue={mapping[this.state.selectedId]}`

Comment: @YuqinXu, and also change `defaultValue=mapping[{id_of_this_select_object}]` to `defaultValue={mapping[id_of_this_select_object]}`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using React, you could just do this:

```
mapping = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c'}

<div> 
     {
       Object.keys(mapping).map(i=>{
          return (
            <select defaultValue={mapping[i]} id={i} />
          )
        })
     }
</div>
```

UPDATE:
 If you just want `select`'s default value to be based on mapping. You could do something like this:

```
  state:{
   defaultId: 1
  }
  someMethodChangingDefaultId(currentId){
    this.setState({id: currentId})
  }
```

Then, in `.render`:

```
  <select defaultValue={mapping[this.state.defaultId]} id={this.state.defaultId} />
```

Comment: Thanks ABGR, I have updated the question. I don't want all keys in mapping to be returned. I would need to let the defaultValue updating with the change of id.